# unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR (line 59)

Tags: php, sql, syntax

I'm making a little project for somebody. 
Now i'm new to messing with files in php but i managed to get it to run on localhost using Mamp. Anyway, now i wanted to upload a test version online and when i'm trying to login i get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home/fcom2126/public_html/bael/admin/overview.php on line 59
```

I have no idea what this error means, by searching around it could be a $ missing somewhere but i can't see where. Maybe you guys can help me out?

```
if (!in_array((new SplFileInfo($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']))->getExtension(), array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
            exit('<p>Foute extentie. Enkel afbeeldingen toegelaten!</p>');
        } else {
            $path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']);
            $_FILES['afbeelding']['name'] = $name . "." . $path_parts['extension'];
            //!!! aanpassen bij UPLOAD
            $img = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/img/rouwregister/overledenen/". $_FILES['afbeelding']['name'];
        }
```

The if sentence is line 59, on my localhost i don't get any error but when trying it out on the web it does give me an error.

Where is my fault?
Thanks beforehand

Pieter-Jan

### EDIT

Could it be that SPL isn't supported in my php version yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your localhost is running PHP5.4+ and your production server is running PHP5.3 or older. As a result you do not have access to class member access on instantiation:

So this:

```
 (new SplFileInfo($_FILES['afbeelding']['name']))->getExtension()
```

won't work. You need to change it to:

```
$splFileInfo = new SplFileInfo($_FILES['afbeelding']['name'])
$extension   = $splFileInfo->getExtension();
if (!in_array($extension, array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
```

Comment: Suspected as much. Thanks for the fix aswel!

Comment: Congrats on the **100k** there John - 'tis indeed a grand day ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you! Technically I have 34 more points to go but thanks to rounding I get a head start on celebrating. =)

Comment: Indeed a pleasure John. I added my contribution here ;-) Not far to go! *Cheers*